# How do I set the selected value of a drop down list in a jTemplate?

Tags: jquery, jtemplates

I'm using [jTemplates](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/) to create several elements of my form based on data returned from the server. I'm able to set the value of `input` fields without any problems but I'm having trouble setting the selected value of a drop down list.

I've tried using a jQuery selector to set the value within the template itself which didn't work. It just added a `[object Object]` right above my drop down. I've also tried using a bunch of `{#if}` statements (see below) which also hasn't worked.

Any thoughts?

**Calling jTemplate:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#my_container').setTemplateURL("templates/MyTemplate.htm", [], { filter_data: false, runnable_functions: true }).processTemplate(data);
</script>
```

**My simplified template:**

```
<table id="expense_table_{$T.ID}">
  <tr>
    <td width="80">
      <input type="text" id="my_amount" class="amount numbersOnly" value="{$T.Amount}" />
    </td>
    <td width="180">
      <select id="my_type" class="my-type">
        {#if $T.MyTypeID == 1} 
          <option value="1" selected>Option 1</option>
        {#else}
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        {#/if}
        {#if $T.MyTypeID == 2} 
          <option value="2" selected>Option 2</option>
        {#else}
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        {#/if}
        {#if $T.MyTypeID == 3} 
          <option value="3" selected>Option 3</option>
        {#else}
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        {#/if}
        {#if $T.MyTypeID == 4} 
          <option value="4" selected>Option 4</option>
        {#else}
          <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        {#/if}        
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the template I posted with all of the `{#if}` statements in my original question works after all. It sure doesn't seem like an ideal solution though, especially for drop down lists with a lot of options. I'll mark this question as answered unless someone can come up with a better solution.